# creation of object array

Tags: java

Actually i had been practicing some of the java programs today(trying to learn it myself). I am trying to  write a program which accepts as many employee details from the user and displaying it. I wrote the code for the same, but failed. There where no compile errors. I tried to create an ArrayList to place the details got from the user. But not very sure how that be done. Or should that be done by using an object array?

Can anyone help me? Also please do suggest any ways by which i can improve my coding. I'll be really thankful.

Below given is my code :

```
public class EmployeeList{

    String empname;
    String empaddress;
    int empage;

    public void getEmployeeDetails(){
        try{
            final BufferedReader br =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Name :");
            empname = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Address :");
            empaddress = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Age :");
            empage = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        }

        catch(final IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void displayEmployeeDetails(){
        System.out.println("Name :" + empname);
        System.out.println("Address :" + empaddress);
        System.out.println("Age : " + empage);
    }
}
```

SerialisePersonList.java

```
public class SerialisePersonList{

    public static void main(final String[] args){
        final EmployeeList emp = new EmployeeList();
        System.out.println("Enter 3 person details");
        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter details of person" + i);
            final List details = new ArrayList();
            details.add(emp.getEmployeeDetails());
        }

        System.out.println("The entered person Details are as following");
        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
            System.out.println("Details of person" + i);
            emp.displayEmployeeDetails();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please re-paste and your code and highlight using the code-formatter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create arraylist before cycle scope and add particular empoloyee in cycle

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
           List<EmployeeList> details = new ArrayList<EmployeeList>();  
           System.out.println("Enter 3 person details");
           for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
           {
               System.out.println("Enter details of person"+i);
               EmployeeList emp =new EmployeeList();
               emp.getEmployeeDetails();
               details.add(emp);
           }

           System.out.println("The entered person Details are as following");
           for(EmployeeList employee : details)
           {
               System.out.println("Details of person");
               employee.displayEmployeeDetails();
           }
        }
```

Comment: `i` is out of scope in the second `for`.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions in addition to Vladimir's changes:

1. Rename `EmployeeList` to `Employee`
2. Make `List` and `ArrayList` generic: `List<Employee>` and `ArrayList<Employee>`

Answer (score 0):

- You called `Class EmployeeList` but
  conceptually it's `Class Employee` because it
  represents one employee, not a list
  of them.
- Getter methods should return something (not to be void),
  in this case you should rename
  `getEmployeeDetails()` to
  `readEmployeeDetails()` that makes more sense.
- `emp` and `details` shouldn't be final, they are not constants, they are variables.
- You should create a new Employee object for each i in main method.

I think you made a bit of confusion about list and element belonging to the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Employee{

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private int age;

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static Employee read() throws Exception{
        Employee tmp = new Employee();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));       

        System.out.println("Name :");
        tmp.setName(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Address :");
        tmp.setAddress(br.readLine());
        System.out.println("Age :");
        tmp.setAge(Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()));

        return tmp;
    }

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Name :" + this.name);
        System.out.println("Address :" + this.address);
        System.out.println("Age : " + this.age);
    }
}
```

Followed by

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class SerialisePersonList{

    public static void main(final String[] args){
        ArrayList<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        System.out.println("Enter details for 3 people");
        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter details of person " + i);

            try{
                list.add(Employee.read());
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The entered person Details are as following");
        for(Employee emp : list){
            System.out.println("======================");
            emp.display();
        }
    }
}
```

Should cover it